# jxbrowse microphone not working, unable to record voice

Tags: jxbrowser

My microphone is not being detected by `JXBrowser`.

Is any way is available to enable microphone in JXBrowser?

```
Browser browser = new Browser();
BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setSize(700, 500);
frame.setVisible(true);

browser.loadURL("https://www.google.com");
```

When try to access Google voice, below message are coming in `jxbrowser`, but this voice recognition working with Google chrome which installed in my PC:

[image: Microphone Not Working]

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this behavior is that Voice recognition functionality hasn't been enabled in JxBrowser library yet. We reproduced this behavior and created appropriate task in our issue tracking system (#751). In one of the next version it will be fixed.

**UPD:** The Voice recognition functionality has been enabled in JxBrowser 6.8. You can read about how to configure JxBrowser to use voice search in the article at https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000099117-voice-recognition